# How to Use Mklink Batch-files with FOR command? (Automatic Junction-Point Recreation)

Tags: windows-7, batch, mklink

I'm trying to create a batch-file that creates (**DIR**) junction points; I commonly use.
Bellow is a script, which creates multiple links, to the same location.

> @echo off 
>   for /f %%i in (input.txt) do ( 
>   mklink /j "%%i" "C:\test" )
>   pause

How do I modify it to use: **(input.txt) for links** , and then **(output.txt) for targets**?

Answer (score 0):

Does the input data *have* to be in two separate files? For example, if your Input.txt looks like this:

```
Link 1|Target 1
Link 2|Target 2
Link 3|Target 3
...
```

Then you can use something like this:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%i in (Input.txt) do @mklink /j "%%i" "%%j"
```